# Is there a difference in the way we access elements of a list comprehension and the elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, list-comprehension

I am working on a genetic algorithm code. I am fairly new to python. 
My code snippet is as follows:

```
    import numpy as np
    pop_size = 10       # Population size
    noi = 2         # Number of Iterations
    M = 2               # Number of Phases in the Data

    alpha = [np.random.randint(0, 64, size = pop_size)]* M
    phi = [np.random.randint(0, 64, size = pop_size)]* M

    reduced_tensor = [np.zeros((pop_size,3,3))]* M

    for n_i in range(noi):

        alpha_en = [(2*np.pi*alpha/63.00) for alpha in alpha]
        phi_en = [(phi/63.00) for phi in phi]


        for i in range(M):
            for j in range(pop_size):
                reduced_tensor[i][j] = [[1, 0, 0],
                                       [0, phi_en[i][j], 0],
                                       [0, 0, 0]]
```

1. Here I have a list of numpy arrays. The variable 'alpha' is a list containing two numpy arrays. How do I use list comprehension in this case? I want to create a similar list 'alpha_en' which operates on every element of alpha. How do I do that? I know my current code is wrong, it was just trial and error.
2. What does 'for alpha in alpha' mean (line 11)? This line doesn't give any error, but also doesn't give the desired output. It changes the dimension and value of alpha.
3. The variable 'reduced_tensor' is a list of an array of 3x3 matrix, i.e., four dimensions in total. How do I differentiate between the indexing of a list comprehension and a numpy array? I want to perform various operations on a list of matrices, in this case, assign the values of phi_en to one of the elements of the matrix reduced_tensor (as shown in the code). How should I do it efficiently? I think my current code is wrong, if not just confusing.

Comment: It is not a good idea to ask several questions in in one post. It reduces your chance of getting a good answer and also increases the risk of the question being closed for being too broad. I suggest you edit your question to include one specific issue and move forward step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There some questionable programming in these 2 lines

```
    alpha = [np.random.randint(0, 64, size = pop_size)]* M
    ...
    alpha_en = [(2*np.pi*alpha/63.00) for alpha in alpha]
```

The first makes an array, and then makes a list with `M` pointers to the same thing.  Note, M copies of the random array.  If I were to change one element of `alpha`, I'd change them all.  I don't see the point to this type of construction.

The `[... for alpha in alpha]` works because the 2 uses of `alpha` are different. At least in newer Pythons the `i` in `[i*3 for i in range(3)]` does not 'leak out' of the comprehension.  That said, I would not approve of that variable naming.  At the very least is it confusing to readers.

The arrays in `alpha_en` are separate.  Values are derived from the array in `alpha`, but they are new.

```
for a in alphas:
    a *= 2
```

would modify each array in `alphas`; how ever due to how `alphas` is constructed this ends up multiplying the array many times.

```
reduced_tensor = [np.zeros((pop_size,3,3))]* M
```

has the same problem; it's a list of M references to the same 3d array.

```
reduced_tensor[i][j]
```

references the `i` reference in that list, and the `j` 'row' of that array.  I like to use

```
reduced_tensor[i][j,:,:]
```

to make it clearer to me and my reader the expected dimensions of the result.

The iteration over `M` does nothing for you; it just repeats the same assignment M times.

At the root of your problems is that use of list replication.

```
In [30]: x=[np.arange(3)]*3

In [31]: x
Out[31]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2])]

In [32]: [id(i) for i in x]
Out[32]: [3036895536, 3036895536, 3036895536]

In [33]: x[0] *= 10

In [34]: x
Out[34]: [array([ 0, 10, 20]), array([ 0, 10, 20]), array([ 0, 10, 20])]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was unaware that I am just creating pointers to the same array. In this case, how would I use list comprehension to modify the matrices? Or is it advisable to use for loops only?

Comment: Use a list comprehension to make a new list. Use regular iteration if you want to work on the elements of a list, as in my `for a in alphas:` clip.  It's hard, if not impossible to change the elements of a list with list comprehension, `[i[0]=0 for i in alpha]` gives an syntax error.